# AWS Backup not creating backups with AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup, aws-organizations, aws-backup

I’m trying to set up AWS Backup with AWS Organizations and I’m having trouble getting the backups to be created. Here are the steps I’ve taken:

In AWS Organizations, I went to policies and enabled backup policies.

I created a backup policy with the following JSON:

```
{
  "plans": {
    "main-backup-plan-eu-central-1": {
      "regions": {
        "@@assign": [
          "eu-central-1"
        ]
      },
      "rules": {
        "main-backup-vault-eu-central-1": {
          "schedule_expression": {
            "@@assign": "cron(6 20/1 ? * * *)"
          },
          "start_backup_window_minutes": {
            "@@assign": "60"
          },
          "complete_backup_window_minutes": {
            "@@assign": "120"
          },
          "lifecycle": {
            "delete_after_days": {
              "@@assign": "14"
            }
          },
          "target_backup_vault_name": {
            "@@assign": "backup-vault"
          }
        }
      },
      "selections": {
        "tags": {
          "backup-assignment": {
            "iam_role_arn": {
              "@@assign": "arn:aws:iam::$account:role/cross-account-backup-role"
            },
            "tag_key": {
              "@@assign": "bkp_schedule"
            },
            "tag_value": {
              "@@assign": [
                "hourly"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I set the target to my AWS dev account.

In the dev account, I created a backup vault and an IAM role named **cross-account-backup-role** with the **AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup** and **AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForRestores** policies attached.

Then i added the tag to an EC2.

Despite these steps, the backup plan is running but no backups are being created. The resources I want to back up have the bkp_schedule tag with the value hourly.

[image]
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue or how I can troubleshoot it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of vault name. The name in the account was backup_vault instead of backup-vault.